# (SSMS) SQL: use CASE to get a person's "Age" (as number) if alive and "RIP" (as text) if dead in the same column

Tags: sql, sql-server, case

**[SOLVED]** https://stackoverflow.com/a/66287009/7657958

Apologies if this question is a duplicate. Spent 3h now trying all kinds of methods to solve my problem, but with no avail! Any help appreciated!

```
PROGRAM: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio
EXPERIENCE: 2-3 weeks (Beginner)

PROGRAM VERSION:
SQL Server Management Studio               15.0.18369.0
SQL Server Management Objects (SMO)        16.100.46041.41
Microsoft Analysis Services Client Tools   15.0.19342.0
Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC)    10.0.18362.1
Microsoft MSXML                            3.0 6.0 
Microsoft .NET Framework                   4.0.30319.42000
Operating System                           10.0.18363
```

I'm trying to autofill an **age column** with information depending on the vital status of a person. For this I have a **column** named **Vital status** (uses varchar) where it displays the status *ALIVE* or *DECEASED* for every person in the table. If the person is alive, his/hers age (a number) should be displayed in the **Age column** (uses varchar). However, if the person is dead, it should instead display R.I.P (text). The age is based on the year the person is born, for this I have a separate **column Born** (uses int) displaying the year.

```
Example: the result should look like this.

--------------------------------------------------
  ID  |   Name   | Born  | Vital status |   Age  |
--------------------------------------------------
  1   |  Arnold  | 1992  |    Alive     |    29  |
  2   |  Bruce   | 1952  |    Deceased  |  R.I.P |
  3   |  Arnie   | 1972  |    Deceased  |  R.I.P |
  4   |  Bruno   | 1962  |    Deceased  |    58  |
```

**This is my latest attempt:**

```
insert into My_Family_Tree (Age)
VALUES(
CASE
WHEN [Vital status] = 'Deceased' THEN 'R.I.P'
ELSE CONVERT(varchar(30), DATEDIFF(year, Born, 2021))
END)
```

which gives me the error on [Vital status] and Born, saying invalid columns. However they both exist in my table. I've also tried reversing this:

```
insert into My_Family_Tree (Age)
VALUES(
CASE
WHEN 'Vital status' = 'Alive' THEN CONVERT(varchar(30), DATEDIFF(year, 'Birthday', 2020))
ELSE 'RIP'
END)
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Clearly you can't have both text and a numeric value in the same column without converting the numeric type to text. Also, it would help greatly if you had added a tag for the specific DBMS you're using, as strongly suggested in the description of the SQL tag you added.

Comment: Aaah shoot!! My apology guys! Worked all day up until late when I wrote this and completely forgot. Continued until 04.00 in the morning.

Comment: @KenWhite: Upated my question again! Hope it helps, if anything else is missing let me know! What regards your answer. Of course, I'm aware of that, hence why I'm using CONVERT to convert my int to an string to achieve just that. It's just that I'm not getting the rest of the code correct.

Comment: SSMS is not a DBMS. It's a tool you use for working with SQL Server databases. SQL Server is the DBMS. I've edited the tags for you. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I think you want an `update`.  Second, you don't have the *date* of birth.  You just have the year.

So, I think you want:

```
update My_Family_Tree
    set Age = (CASE WHEN [Vital status] = 'Deceased'
                    THEN 'R.I.P'
                    ELSE CONVERT(varchar(30), 2021 - Born)
               END)
```

Comment: Much appreciation. This solved my problem! Just a small edit, you forgot a closing-bracket at the end, after 'Born, for the CONVERT. Thanks for the tip regarding DATEDIFF. I thought it was possible to use without the need of month and day as well. Cheers!